# Javascript não carrega todas as funções

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, click, eventos, event-listener

Tenham (um|uma) (ótimo|ótima) (dia|tarde|noite)!

### Pois bem!

Ao inserir **muitas** funções num `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` o meu código passa a não executar todas elas! 
O console do navegador **não mostra** nenhum erro, e as executa normalmente se eu chamá-las pelo console, porém, se eu as chamar pelo código, o script não as executa, nem mesmo mostra esse erro a seguir: function chamada is undefined.
Então criei um arquivo JS externo pensando que poderia ser a quantidade de funções (em torno de 20 funções por exemplo)  mas nada adiantou!
Pesquisei então. Achei num certo site por aí, me esqueci qual foi, que sugeriu acrescentar no  o atributo **language="javascript"**: `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">/*Código aqui*/</script>`
Adiantou **:D**...por pouco tempo. **:/**
Ao acrescentar mais algumas funções, o código não executa mais. Mas se eu as chamar assim na barra de endereço: **javascript:nomeDaFunção()**; ou assim no console: **nomeDaFunção()** ela funciona normalmente. 
Para não abrir outra questão duplicada já vi aqui no stackoverflow questões parecidas. O problema destas é que as pessoas coloca as funções dentro de outras funções, assim, elas não ficam globais; oque não é o meu caso. O que poderia ser?
Endereço do código: http://leonardolima.epizy.com/calendario.php

**Para testar, clique no ano de 2016.**

Comment: Coloca o seu código aqui ou disponibiliza de alguma forma.

Comment: Acresentei a url do código

Comment: Pressione a tecla F12 para abrir o Console e veja se está aparecendo algum erro ao carregar seu script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### var Problema = 'Resolvido';

Graças a Deus, consegui! O problema, ou melhor, a questão não é "Javascript não carrega todas as funções". 
**Pois bem, vou procurar ser claro!**

Eu criei um app (calendário). e aparece nele três menus:

- Lista de anos;
- Lista de Meses;
- Menu de edição do Mês;

[image: Lista de Anos]
[image: Lista de Meses]
[image: Menu de edição de mês]

No menu de edição de mês é informado se neste mês o contribuidor vai pagar no valor normal/promocional.

Criei no menu Lista de meses um submenu chamado GERENCIAR:

[image: Mês com o]

Para não ficar de um por um editando. o membro da equipe seleciona todos os meses dando um click em cada mês, assim, abre esse menu para apagar; definir como valor promocional ou valor normal os meses selecionados.

O que aconteceu no meu problema é que a função que eu criei nomeada **abrirOptionMes**(antigamente, ao postar essa questão neste "fórum", se chamava **abrirOpçãoMes**) foi chamada quando a página foi carregada. O problema é que as listas de meses do **anoX** são criadas apenas quando o membro clicar duas vezes no ano que quer editar. Assim, o script criará as listas e escreverá todas elas em html. Isso  significa que a função **abrirOptionMes** na hora em que foi chamada não achou os meses, (que ainda não existiam no HTML) para aplicar o evento `addEventListener()` e então ela ficou invalidada.

### #SOLUÇÃO

Tão simples esta solução que nem precisava de um tópico. Mas como alguém pode ter problemas como o meu; então vamos lá. 
É Apenas uma questão de lógica.

**Basta aplicarmos o evento, por exemplo: `document.addEventListener('click',abrirOptionMes)` na mesma função que insere a lista de meses após ser adicionado os meses.**

Exemplo ilustrativo:

```
function insereMes(){
this.addMes=function(){
var minhaLi,htmlOuter='';
for(var i=0;i<=12;i++){
/*Gera em javascript os elementos <li>*/
var minhaLi=[],htmlOuter='';
minhaLi[i]=document.createElement("li");
minhaLi[i].innerText='01';
htmlOuter+=minhaLi[0].outerHTML
}
/*Insere todas as LI's e depois cria o evento addEventListener:*/
$('body > div#exemplo > ul').html(htmlOuter);document.addEventListener('click',abrirOptionMes)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu navegador o seu script está com uma codificação toda estranha, o nome de uma função está `function modMesesOpÃ§Ã£o`, experimente mudar a codificação e veja se retorna alguma coisa diferente.

Comment: Quanto a este problema de codificação: o código é escrito em UTF-8 e mesmo assim é visto como carácter desconhecido pelo servidor [Infinity Free](http://infinityfree.net). Mas não era este o problema. Já foi resolvido.